# golang: run default application for a pdf file on windows

Tags: windows, go

I'd like to open a PDF file in the filesystem from go with the default application. How can I do that? From the command line I just write the filename of the pdf file and the application opens (with the requested file). When I try to use `exec.Command()` I get an error (not surprisingly) `exec: "foo.pdf": executable file not found in %PATH%`.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("foo.pdf")
    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must launch `cmd /C start foo.pdf`. This will let the start command find the correct executable for you.

```
cmd := exec.Command("cmd", "/C start path_to_foo.pdf")
```

Comment: I think opening a filename with spaces in it should be possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13692919/395461 But I couldn't get the command to work properly in Go, even though it would when entered manually on the command line.

Comment: Is there a cross platform way to do this?

Answer (score 14):

```
exec.Command("rundll32.exe", "url.dll,FileProtocolHandler", "path_to_foo.pdf")
```

should also handle it.

Note that still the right way to do it is to use a C wrapper around the [`ShellExecute()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153) API function exported by `shell32.dll`, and the ["w32" library](https://github.com/AllenDang/w32) seems to provide this wrapper right away.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file like this:

```
//go:generate mkwinsyscall -output zmain.go main.go
//sys shellExecute(hwnd int, oper string, file string, param string, dir string, show int) (err error) = shell32.ShellExecuteW
package main

const sw_shownormal = 1

func main() {
   shellExecute(0, "", "file.pdf", "", "", sw_shownormal)
}
```

Then build:

```
go mod init pdf
go generate
go mod tidy
go build
```

https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows/mkwinsyscall